# Mysql min function on a column and an integer

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I've got a table which contains a column named size.

I want with a min function to find the min value of size and a set of integer.

For example : 
Size can be : 5, 10, 15
And I want to find the min result in a set like :
MIN(size,1)

Min method does not seem to have several parameters...

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT min(1, size) FROM myTable
SELECT min(SELECT 1,size FROM myTable) FROM myTable
```

There is error for each of these syntax.
I precise that I can't do the comparison in my code because the sql is generated and can be something more complex like:

```
SELECT min(SELECT size FROM table1, SELECT size FROM table2, 10)
FROM table3
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`least`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) to find the minimum across columns/expressions and `min` to find the minimum across rows.

```
SELECT min(least(1, size)) FROM myTable
```

Or this would probably be more efficient actually

```
SELECT least(1,min(size)) FROM myTable
```